# Getting column cannot be null while trying to use 'insert into select' query

Tags: mysql, sql

insert into TABLE1
    (id,table2id)

```
values
(
    1,
    (select distinct id from TABLE2 s table2 where table2.data='ABC')

);
```

Let us say table2id column of TABLE1 is not nullable. But, (select distinct id from TABLE2 s table2 where table2.data='ABC') query can potentially return null. How to make the above query insert into TABLE1 when (select distinct id from TABLE2 s table2 where table2.data='ABC') query is not returning null without getting 'table2id cannot be null' error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace 0 with any value you want

```
insert into TABLE1 (id,table2id)
values
(
    1,
    COALESCE((SELECT DISTINCT id FROM TABLE2 as table2 WHERE table2.data = 'ABC'),0))
);
```

Comment: It would be nicer to use `COALESCE` or `IFNULL` rather than writing the query twice.

Comment: Using COALESCE like below worked for me.    INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id, table2id)
VALUES
    (1, COALESCE((SELECT DISTINCT id FROM TABLE2 as table2 WHERE table2.data = 'ABC'),0));         Thanks. Everyone.

Comment: Thanks both for the comments, I updated my answer to include your remarks.